# Wordpress - Redirect a page if the page doesn't exist

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to redirect a user from; `website.com/properties/property-title` to `website.com/archive_properties/property-title` if the URL doesn't exist.

The below code is working if the URL that it is redirecting to is actually a page, if the page doesn't exist then I get an error; redirected you too many times and the URL is changed to `/archive_archive_archive_archive_archive_archive_archive_archive_archive_archive_archive_properties/property-title`

Is there a way I can just display the normal 404 page if the page doesn't exist?

```
add_filter( '404_template', function( $template ) {

    $request = filter_input( INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_URI', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );

    if ( ! $request ) {
        return $template;
    }
    $regex = [
        '/properties/'    => 'archive_properties/$1',
    ];

    foreach( $regex as $pattern => $replacement ) {
        if ( ! preg_match( $pattern, $request ) ) {
            continue;
        }
        $url = preg_replace( $pattern, $replacement, $request );

        wp_redirect( $url, 301 );
        exit;
    }

    // not our business, let WP do the rest.
    return $template;

}, -4000 ); // hook in quite early
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may just forgot a forward slash for the regex value.

```
'/properties/'    => '/archive_properties/$1',
```

**Edit:**

So the issue is your `preg_replace` parameters. `$pattern` is a delimited regex patter and if you want it to be matching `/properties/`, you can use `#` for deliminator so it becomes `#/properties/#`. And the `$replacement` should be `/archive_properties/`. This is the actual string replacement (not regex).

This is then

```
'#/properties/#'    => '/archive_properties/'.
```

You do need to also take care of the case where the URL just ends with `/properties`. I think you should do a conditional OR check for the URI, then if it's true, replace just `/properties` which takes care of both cases.

Comment: When I add that instead of going to website.com/archive_properties it just goes to /archive_properties (without the website address before)

Comment: The issue is with your REQUEST_URI. Dump the $request var to see what it actually is.

Comment: @TurtleTread, I came across your suggestion for a similar challenge I'm having. Changing the pattern to `#/([a-zA-Z\-]+)/#' => '/staff/$1/'`, gets me a step closer unless the page ends a slash e.g. `jacob/` rather than jacob. With ` jacob/` it returns a 414 error. I'm at a lost why `jacob` returns a 404 page but `jacob/` throws it and a 414 error is displayed. What am I missing?